# Saving a Dictionary of Pointers to File

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

I'm trying to create  a family tree in python, and I want to create a dictionary of Persons, where the key is the person's first name and the value is a Person object for that name.

I can create the dictionary fine, and I can save it fine using the below code.

```
import os, ast

myFile = open( FILE, "r+" )     # Opens the file for reading and writing

tree = myFile.read()

if tree == "":
    tree = {}
else:
    tree = ast.literal_eval(tree)


def save():
    myFile.write(str(tree))
    myFile.close()
```

However, when I reload my program and try to read in the dictionary, I get the following error:

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
    {'Charlie': <__main__.Person object at 0x00000000032DB860>}
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suspect that the evaluator can't recognize the object because once the program closes the pointer no longer exists. Is there a way I can save my dictionary so that I can reload it and have access to all my Person objects' data without losing it each time my program closes?

Comment: Use pickle, it's easy: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle (or cPickle to go faster) http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (dictionary, class, save, read) will not help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1):

`ast.literal_eval` is not meant for evaluating and understanding custom objects. It's used to evaluate strings and literals *safely*. You need to serialize your data by using something like [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html).

```
>>> import pickle
>>> class Person(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name  
... 
>>> persons = {'Charlie': Person('Charlie')}
>>> with open(FILE, "wb") as my_file:
...     pickle.dump(persons, my_file)
...
>>> with open(FILE, "rb") as f:
...     result = pickle.load(f)
...     
... 
>>> result
{'Charlie': <__main__.Person object at 0x1598bd0>}
```

When you have large (or many) objects, you can use `cPickle` in which the pickling is done in C instead of python thus providing a major speed increase.

If object serialization is something you have not heard about before, please [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).